# Typescript - Rendering Connected Components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Using TypeScript and React/Redux, I have typed a ConnectedComponent. But when I try to render that component, TypeScript is throwing an error saying that the required props aren't passed.

Ex.

```
interface Props extends MapStateProps {

}

class App extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </>
    );
  }
}

interface MapStateProps {
  user: UserState;
}

const MapStateToProps = (state: AppState): MapStateProps => ({
  user: state.user,
});

const connectedApp = connect(MapStateToProps, null)(App);

export {
  connectedApp as App,
};
```

Then when I render the component like:

```
<App />
```

It says that App requires the 'user' prop. How can I do this without setting the user prop as optional?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this and see if it helps.

```js
interface UserState{}
interface AppState{
  user: UserState;
}
interface MapStateProps {
  user: UserState;
}
interface Props extends MapStateProps {}

class App2 extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <div>
          App2
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const MapStateToProps = (state: AppState): MapStateProps => ({
  user: state.user,
});

export default connect(MapStateToProps, null)(App2);
```

Comment: I tried that as well, but can never get that to work. It always says that mapStateToProps doesn't satisfy StateProps.

Comment: @hairyhendrix I have modified code and this one was working for me. It seems your *MapStateProps* interface and *AppState* interface user type is different in both.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
export {
  connectedApp as App,
};
```

With the default export:

```
export default connectedApp;
```

And then the import

```
import {App} from './App';
```

For

```
import App from './App';
```

Comment: I tried that before, and again now, and unfortunately it has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

```
//...

const connectedApp = connect(MapStateToProps, null)(App);

export default connectedApp ;
export { connectedApp as App};
```